# How to prevent quotes being output as html escape codes in c#

Tags: c#, episerver

I'm not actually sure this is c# per se but I'm working in a .cshtml file (in episerver).

I'm setting a string variable that includes quotes. This is a simplified version:

```
@{
    var backgroundcontent = "class='background' data-transition='mytransition'";
    if (Model.CurrentBlock.Photo) {
        backgroundcontent = "class='photo' data-transition='none'";
    }
  }
```

When this is rendered in the page, I'm getting `&#39;` which is great if I'm rendering it inside a tag, but not when I need it in the tag itself.

Am I stuck with the html quotes (and have to do something more complicated like setting two variables for the attributes), or is there a way to override them?

Comment: Can you provide the cshtml code snippet that is rendering `backgroundcontent` to the view?  Razor (.cshtml) will automatically escape strings based on the context of how you try to render them

Comment: The answer below is correct, but in your case I would actually have two variables instead.

Comment: @Tim I was rendering it with `@backgroundcontent`, but `@Html.Raw(@backgroundcontent)` did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Html.Raw(backgroundcontent);`, this should prevent default string escaping.

Comment: Yup that works. I swear I tried it previously but perhaps I didn't preface it with '@'.